Can a liquid become supersaturated by a dissolved gas when going from a lower to a higher pressure?
This question has spawned from a discussion between myself (a novice diver but an engineer), and a diving instructor.
The training materials indicate that if you are driving and go from sea level, to an arbitrary higher altitude (assuming the gas mix remains constant), and then return to sea level after a short period, it is possible to have more total dissolved nitrogen in your body than when you started your ascent from sea-level. Which would indicate that your blood/tissue has become super-saturated with nitrogen going from a lower to a higher pressure.
My understanding tells me that this is impossible.
When you start ascending (higher to lower pressure), you become super-saturated as the solubility of nitrogen decreases at a lower pressure. This causes you to off-gas and lowers the total amount of nitrogen in your tissues until you reach the saturation/equilibrium point of the higher altitude (or start descending again).
When you're descending on the other side, the solubility of nitrogen increases, so you're no longer saturated and your tissues take on more nitrogen. This process continues until you hit your bottom altitude (sea level) and eventually become saturated at that new altitude.
As such, on the other side you should have less than or an equal amount of dissolved nitrogen as where you started.
Plotting altitude, pressure, and dissolved NO2 against time on a graph by my reckoning should give you something like this.

Now, this guy is far more experienced at diving than me, and this isn't my field of expertise so am I missing something or is the training material mistaken?

Are you talking about underwater diving or ascending to high altitudes above sea level? They are very different things.

@VincentThacker - I'm on about what happens if you're driving to a dive site going over a big hill/mountain on the way. So you're at sea level equilibrium/saturation when you start, and you haven't dived yet on the other end. If you know about Tissue Codes, this discussion arose because the BSAC training materials indicate that you can go from an A code to a B code by driving over a hill... Which would indicate you have more nitrogen load after going over a hill than before, which I don't understand how it could be possible

I believe this question has more to do with biology and chemistry than with physics, however a process similar to that describe in the question is used in chemical industries.

The process known as Pressure Swing Adsorption (PSA) operates on the principle that gases are more likely to adhere to solid surfaces under elevated pressures. This adherence is termed "adsorption," and its extent increases with pressure. Conversely, reducing the pressure allows the gas to detach or "desorb." PSA is adept at separating gas mixtures due to the varying degrees of adsorption exhibited by different gases on a specific solid surface. For instance, when air—a mixture of gases—is propelled at high pressure through a container with a zeolite adsorbent bed, which has a higher affinity for nitrogen than oxygen, nitrogen is selectively retained in the bed. Consequently, the gas that emerges from the container is oxygen-enriched compared to the incoming air mixture. Once the bed's nitrogen adsorption capacity is reached, it can be "regenerated" by lowering the pressure to release the nitrogen, rendering it ready for a new cycle to produce air with elevated oxygen levels.

From thermodynamics perspective increased nitrogen levels after driving over a hill is impossible hence, it's quite possible that nitrogen is getting "adsorbed" on tissues and has less tendency to "desorb" at lower pressures. This results in accumulation of nitrogen which is being expressed as excess nitrogen levels..

Does this apply? The quote you gave refers to solid surfaces, not liquid ones. I have asked a similar question over in Bio SE though if you don't think that a pure thermodynamic explanation doesn't necessarily prove the training materials are mistaken

Tissues are solid

The gas isn't dissolving into the solid part of the tissue though, is it? It's dissolving into the mucous membrane of your lungs initially
